# Core plot: first/last point symbol is out of screen

Tags: ios, core-plot, symbols

I have a simple question, yet I have no idea how to solve it.

When I am laying out my plot, I am using CPTPlotSymbol for each point. The symbol is a circle. The problem is that only half of the circle is visible on the first and last point.(due to the position of the plot). Is there a way I can display the full symbol inside the plot ?

I have already tried to increase the padding of the plot and the plot area but none worked.

Thanks and regards,

Petar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand the offending plot range to make room for the symbols. Use the `visibleRange` and `gridLinesRange` to constrain the size of axis and grid lines. Here is some code from the Control Chart in the Plot Gallery example app that does this:

```
CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [[plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy] autorelease];
CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [[plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy] autorelease];

x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = yRange.location;
y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = xRange.location;

x.visibleRange = xRange;
y.visibleRange = yRange;

x.gridLinesRange = yRange;
y.gridLinesRange = xRange;

[xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.05)];
[yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromDouble(1.05)];
plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
```